# Ternary operator in SPFx to show hide

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience, reactjs

I am Working on SPFx and writing below code to get current user belong to particular group or not and if its belong then show else hide

below is my interface:

```
UserInGroup:boolean;
```

State:

```
UserInGroup:false
```

and method to get current user belong to particular group or not calling this on component did mount:

```
checkMemberGroups() {
    var absoluteUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl;
    var reactHandler = this;
    var UserGroup = "Admin"
    $.ajax({
            async: false,
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
            },
            method: "GET",
            url: absoluteUri + "/_api/Web/CurrentUser/Groups",

                success: function(data) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.Groups.results.length; i++) {

                        if (data.d.Groups.results[i].Title == UserGroup) {
                         
                          reactHandler.setState({ UserInGroup: !reactHandler.state.UserInGroup });
                          console.log(reactHandler.state.UserInGroup);
                        }
                    }

                },
                error: function(response) {
                    console.log(response.status);
                    
                },
            });
        //return UserInGroup;
    }
```

Below is my render code where need to show and hide li

```
public render(): React.ReactElement<IHomePageProps> {
    <li>
       <div>test</div>
    </li>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use code like below in `render()` method:

```
{
    this.state.UserInGroup ? <li> <div> test </div> </li> : <></>
}
```

Check below links for conditional rendering in react:

1. [Conditional Rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)
2. [Conditional Rendering in React](https://flexiple.com/react/conditional-rendering-in-react)